# Laravel Eloquent: I cannot get the id I want, instead I get another one from a joined table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

This is my first question here, so I hope I don't mess anything up on my first try.

Okay, to the topic in hand: I am trying to do a function in my controller which allows me to both fetch some data from my database in a template and then generate a downloadable PDF file with the data I was passing to it. I managed to do so, and it works perfectly fine.

What's wrong is, I am using a database where all my identifiers are named 'id', and when I try to access the one I want, I get another from the joined tables. The obvious solution would be changing the name of the identifiers, so there are no duplicated names, but due to some external factors, I cannot do that thing, at least for now. That is something programming cannot do.

So, I was wondering if there is a way I can retrieve the id I want, without changing the database.

This is my function:

```
public function descargarPDF(Request $request)
    {
        $fecha1 = $request->get('fecha1');
        $fecha2 = $request->get('fecha2');
        $categoria = $request->get('categoria');
        // These are filters I had to apply before fetching data to my PDF file, they work fine.
        $tickets = DB::table('tickets')
        -> join('detalle_tickets', 'tickets.detalle_ticket_id', '=', 'detalle_tickets.id')
        -> join('users', 'detalle_tickets.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        -> join('areas', 'detalle_tickets.area_id', '=', 'areas.id')
        -> where('tickets.estado' ,'=', $categoria) 
        -> whereBetween('tickets.created_at', [$fecha1, $fecha2]) 
        -> get();
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('/admin/pdf', compact('tickets'));
        return $pdf->download('tickets.pdf');
    }
```

And this is my blade template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>PDF</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Código</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Empresa</th>
                <th>Requerimiento</th>
                <th>Estado</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach($tickets as $value)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $value->id }}</td>
                <td>{{ $value->name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $value->email }}</td>
                <td>{{ $value->empresa }}</td>
                <td>{{ $value->nombre }}</td>
                <td>{{ $value->estado }}</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for your help! Have a nice day :)

Comment: Which table are you getting in the incorrect item from?

Comment: Specify the fields: `->select('tickets.id as id', 'tickets.name as name', '...')`. You can run `dd($tickets)` to see what's inside it.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte It worked like a charm, thank you so much!

Comment: No problem @Dancli . I wrote an answer that you can mark as accepted to help others with the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify just the fields you need:

```
 $tickets = DB::table('tickets')
    ->select('tickets.id as id', 'tickets.name as name', '...')
    -> join('detalle_tickets', 'tickets.detalle_ticket_id', '=', 'detalle_tickets.id')
    -> join('users', 'detalle_tickets.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    -> join('areas', 'detalle_tickets.area_id', '=', 'areas.id')
    -> where('tickets.estado' ,'=', $categoria) 
    -> whereBetween('tickets.created_at', [$fecha1, $fecha2]) 
    -> get();
```

To get more information, use xdebug or write `dd($tickets);`  to see what's inside the variable.

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems all I needed were aliases:

```
public function descargarPDF(Request $request)
    {
        $fecha1 = $request->get('fecha1');
        $fecha2 = $request->get('fecha2');
        $categoria = $request->get('categoria');
        $tickets = DB::table('tickets')
        -> join('detalle_tickets', 'tickets.detalle_ticket_id', '=', 'detalle_tickets.id')
        -> join('users', 'detalle_tickets.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        -> join('areas', 'detalle_tickets.area_id', '=', 'areas.id')
        -> select ('tickets.id as id_ticket',
                   'users.name as nombre',
                   'users.email as email',
                   'users.empresa as empresa',
                   'areas.nombre as requerimiento',
                   'tickets.estado as estado')
        -> where('tickets.estado' ,'=', $categoria) 
        -> whereBetween('tickets.created_at', [$fecha1, $fecha2]) 
        -> get();
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('/admin/pdf', compact('tickets'));
        return $pdf->download('tickets.pdf');
    }
```

Cheers to Felipe for solving that in the comments!